# How to use a 'checkbox' to update shipping address to same as billing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, orchardcms-1.6

So using Orchard CMS 1.6, When the customer creates an account they are prompt for invoice address and shipping address.

I would like a check box, below the invoice address, which will update the shipping address with the same invoice address details, as opposed to having to enter the same address twice.

Not sure how to do it, any help would be much appreciated) an example of the check box would be

```
<div class="checkbox">@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => signup.SameAddress)</div>
<div class="label">@Html.LabelFor(m => signup.SameAddress, T(Use same address as billing"))</div>
```

So far my code looks like this(below). ATM they have to enter the same details twice.

```
<article class="addresses form">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="span5">
        <h2>@T("Invoice Address")</h2>

        <table class="table-bordered table-striped table">
            <colgroup>
                <col id="Col1" />
                <col id="Col2" />
            </colgroup>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">@T("Name")</th>
                    <td>@invoiceAddress.Name.Value</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">@T("AddressLine1")</th>
                    <td>@invoiceAddress.AddressLine1.Value<</td>
                </tr>              
            </thead>
        </table>
        </div>

        //insert checkbox here

        <div class="span5">
        <h2>@T("Billing Address")</h2>
        <table class="table-bordered table-striped table">
            <colgroup>
                <col id="Col1" />
                <col id="Col2" />
            </colgroup>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">@T("Name")</th>
                    <td>@shippingAddress.Name.Value</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">@T("AddressLine1")</th>
                    <td>@shippingAddress.AddressLine1.Value<</td>
                </tr>               
            </thead>

        </table>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    </article>
```

Comment: In your code there is nothing which relates to knockout.js. Why do you think that this is used here?

Comment: Because i'm using knockout mvc, and from the tutorials (http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro) on knockout.js I was hoping I could immediately update the fields from a check box....any ideas or any other suggestions?

Comment: +1 to @nemesv there is no knockout here to help you with.

Comment: well that can you suggest what to use....JQuery?...or offer any advice on how to go about this?